# Should ProviderUserId be kept secret?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I want to seed some user profile data in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application so that I can run some (browser) automated UI tests (for secured areas of the application).

I don't want to store any passwords so I'm only using external OAuth/OpenID authentication providers, e.g. Google.

Is there any reason not to include my Google OpenID URL in a data seed method (which will be committed to a public GitHub repository)?  Should the `ProviderUserId` field (in the `webpages_OAuthMembership` table by default) be kept private/secret?

Are there any better approaches to UI testing a public MVC 4 internet application that only uses external authentication providers?